# Use 1 variable throughout the entire app and where do i initialize it?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton, instance-variables

I have an app and on the first page is a button that the user can set an image which is on the second page. 
To switch pages, the code im using is:

```
- (IBAction)myCart:(id)sender; {
MyCartViewController * cart2 = [[MyCartViewController alloc]init];
cart2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:cart2 animated:YES];
[cart2 release];

}
```

And i also have another method this allows the user to press a button and set an image.

```
- (IBAction)outlet1 {
cart.displayImage = YES; 

}
```

cart is a ivar created in the .h file so i can use it through out the whole file. My problem is that i need to be able to use cart (not cart2) in the myCart method. How can i do this? Because if i try to swtich the cart2's with just cart and i delete the line:
 `MyCartViewController * cart2 = [[MyCartViewController alloc]init];`

the app crashes when i try to switch pages. How can i use the same variable for both methods? Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)myCart:(id)sender {
     MyCartViewController * cart2 = [[MyCartViewController alloc]init];
     cart2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
     [self presentModalViewController:cart2 animated:YES];
      [cart2 release];
}
```

`cart2` is local reference variable and can not persist beyond the method `myCart`. Instead declare it as a part of interface variable and initialize it in the `init` method. Don't forget to release it finally at the end where you are releasing all interface member variables ( in `dealloc`).

Comment: ok. how would you recommend i init the variable in the `init` method? Im pretty new to programming. And will this still work? Because when i remove the first line in the method and try to put it in the interface file, the app crashes when trying to switch pages. And thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: you just helped me figure out a bug that i have had for about a week and i would just like to say THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!! :D

Comment: No problem. Hope you understood your mistake :)

Comment: i sure did! i totally just learned something new. I now realize that i have to initialize ivars in the `init` method and not in the method to be able to use them through out the app! Thanks so much!